# How to check that day is last day of month in php?

Tags: php, date

My previous question: [how-to-find-current-day-no-in-month-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377798/how-to-find-current-day-no-in-month-in-php/21378561?noredirect=1#comment32241440_21378561)

Now I face another problem. Suppose I know that this `monday` is the `4th monday of the current month.` Now how to check that `this monday is also the last monday of the current month`?

```
exa:1 
date: 27-01-2014
```

Using the code below, I get the name and number of a day:

```
day: monday   
day no :4th
```

This is the 4th monday of january and it is also the last monday of january. How to check that?

```
exa:2  
date: 20-01-2014   
day: monday   
day no :3rd
```

Here `this monday is 3rd monday of january but not last monday of january.`

So, in short, when I got a day number then how to check whether that the day number is last or not?

`code:`

```
$t=date('d-m-Y');
$dayName = strtolower(date("D",strtotime($t)));
$dayNum = strtolower(date("d",strtotime($t)));
$dayno = floor(($dayNum - 1) / 7) + 1
```

Comment: date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000)); will get u last day of the month

Comment: no...i don't want last day of month.I am trying to do is check that day is last day of month or not?

Comment: @DS9 check this post you will get the idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/php-last-day-of-the-month

Comment: @DS9: if you know what is the last day, then you can compare current day with last day, don't you think?

Comment: This is not duplicate quetion.I am trying to find that day number is last or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add 7 days (you still have a monday) to the date you have, and check if it's in the same month.

Comment: If we're checking for the last day, why not just add `one` day?

Comment: Read the question, christopher. We need to check if that's last monday in a month, not last day of month.

Comment: @christopher yeah, that's kinda confusing for the question, but I parsed it as "the last day 'like this'", so "is this the last tuesday in this month".

Comment: Apologies. Then this solution makes perfect sense. +1

Comment: Thanks @Nanne for your anser. I got my solution.

Answer (score 6):

The quickest way to check if today is the last of the month I would suggest the following

```
 if(date('t') == date('d')){
    echo 'Last day of the month.';
}
```

This compares the current day with the number of days of the current month.

Comment: This is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

The complete solution is as follow. Thanks to @Oliver M Grech and @Nanne.

```
            $t=date('d-m-Y');
            $day = strtolower(date("D",strtotime($t)));
            $month = strtolower(date("m",strtotime($t)));
            $dayNum = strtolower(date("d",strtotime($t)));
            $weekno = floor(($dayNum - 1) / 7) + 1;

            if($weekno=="4" or $weekno=="5")
            {
                $Date = date("d-m-Y");
                $new_month = date('m', strtotime($Date. ' + 7 days'));
                if($new_month != $month)
                {
                    echo "This ".$day." is last day of month." ;
                }
            }
```